# Mapping spaces for pro-objects in a simplicial model category

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

If $C$ is a simplicial model category (I have simplicial commutative rings in mind), then one can simplicially enrich pro-$C$ over sSet by taking $$\lim_j \mathrm{colim}_i \underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_C(A_i,B_j)$$ for any two pro-systems $A_i$ and $B_j$. Note $\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}$ here denotes the enrichment. These are indexed over small cofiltered indexing categories. This is for example done by Isaksen when he defines a model structure on pro-$C$ given that $C$ is *proper*.

My question is why this isn't $$\mathrm{holim}_j\mathrm{hocolim}_i\underline{\mathrm{Hom}}_C(A_i,B_j)
.$$ Homotopy colimits over filtered indexing categories are presented by the strict colimit (maybe you need some condition on $C$ like combinatorial), so this doesn't cause an issue, but what about the homotopy *limit*?

For example, Galatius and Venkatesh show in their paper "Derived Galois Deformation Rings" that the natural map lim $\to$ holim in the above definition is a weak equivalence (in the Quillen model structure) of simplicial sets if

1. $J$ is cofinite (i.e. $\{j : j < j_0\}$ is finite for all $j_0 \in J$),
2. each $B_j$ is cofibrant, and
3. The maps $B_{j_0} \to \lim_{j<j_0} B_j$ are fibrations for all $j_0$.

In Isaksen's language this means that $B_j$ is *strongly fibrant*.

But since these conditions on $J$ and $B_j$ are not always satisfied (well, the first one is, without loss of generality), I wouldn't expect holim to give lim all this time. So is there some conceptual explanation of why one would take lim instead of holim in the definition?

Comment: I mean, you're never going to get a strictly associative composition using homotopy limits for your hom-spaces. I wouldn't be surprised if you can use a definition like that in an $\infty$-categorical framework.

Comment: Ahh good point, hadn't thought about that.